# Combine php scripts with html bootstrap button

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have some bootstrap button on `page.html`:

```
<button type="button" class="btn">Basic</button>
```

And some PHP script `script.php`.

Is there are any way to combine them, so then user clicks button, script executes and passes the result back to `page.html`?

I've tried to google this question - but there are advises to do it with `Ajax`. But I want to keep the code as simple as possible.

Comment: If you want to keep it basic just link to the script? `<a href="script.php" class="btn">Basic</a>`

Comment: It's basic `html`, as I understand. Any way to link it with bootstrap button?

Comment: Ajax is simple. Let me know if you want an example.

Comment: What you want to do is exactly what AJAX is here for. Any HTML solution need to reload the page since PHP is a server side scripting and so you need the server to parse the PHP to render it. With AJAX you do it without reloading the entire page.

Comment: Would you kindly provide me an example with Ajax then?

Comment: here is some simple ajax example https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write `button` inside a `<form>`  and  you specify the desired target URL in the action attribute of `<form>`.

In case you have form you can use this

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form action="/script.php">
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Basic</button>
</form>
```

or use this for the basic one

```
<a href="/script" class="btn">Basic</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this with AJAX. Example of AJAX function:

```
function sendRequest(type, url, callback, async, params) {
    if (async !== false) async = true;
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = callback;
    xhttp.open(type, url, async);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send(params);
}
```

and this is how you can call it:

```
sendRequest('POST', 'yoururl', function(response) {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        //Handle the response
    }
}, true);
```